# In Java, why do my HttpURLConnection requests occasionally throw an "UnknownHostException"?

Tags: java, apache, http

Over a span of 1 hour, every 10 to 15 seconds, I execute in Java:

```
        conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection(); 
        conn.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; U; Intel Mac OS X 10.4; en-US; rv:1.9.2.2) Gecko/20100316 Firefox/3.6.2");
        BufferedReader bufrdr = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream(), charDcdr));
```

My purpose is to download a bunch of web pages, tokenize them, and store them in a database. I use these documents just for my own study (nothing nefarious).

It almost always works, but every now and then, my connection request throws either an *UnknownHostException* or *NoRouteToHostException*. I catch the exception, wait 10-minutes, and then carry on with the downloading. no problem. But, I am curious.

My requesting pages from a web browser always pulls up a page. Requesting from within Java sometimes fails.

1. Is there some setting on the webserver that detects I am making too many requests (auto downloading), identifies my Java program somehow, and denies my requests? Then, if I wait a few minutes, it lets me continue downloading pages?
2. How is it identifying me?
3. I thought that the code snippet above masks my requests as from a Firefox browser running on a Mac (instead of requests by a Java bot)?
4. Webmasters don't want people auto downloading, right? (but, in my case, I respect that and wait several seconds, or minutes, between requests. And, I only do this for self-study).

Comment: If you want to respect the wishes of webmasters regarding automatic downloads, I suggest you read up on what a "robots.txt" file does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Browsers typically do a retry in a very desperate try to serve you content. You might be able to get more reliable results if you code a simple retry in short time frame yourself. UnknownHostException might be called by slow responding name servers. If you query a larger number of different hosts problems in that area are expected and retries help as well. You might be able to configure a different name server (resolver) on your machine to get a bit more reliable answers.